# Prompt Chrome installation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, google-chrome

Good day,

I'm having a problem at the moment. I would like to know if there is a way of doing this. With the newer technology's like Bootstrap and Angular is not that user friendly in older IE anymore. So is there a way to when you open the site it give you a message to install chrome so it downloads it automatic and when it is finished it will open chrome in the URL you first clicked. All of this I want to happen with C# or JavaScript because it is asp.net sites.

I will appreciate your opinions!

Comment: Hopefully no sane operating system is configured and used such that this is possible. It would be a _huge_ security issue. Users still using some totally outdated browser engine usually have specific reasons for that.

Comment: however, you can detect(from server - User Agent) if user has chrome installed(locally) or not and suggest some url to download and install themselves.. again you need to look that on security perspective.

Comment: Hmmm I don't know about the automatic downloading but what I normally do is use [HTML conditional comments](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_comments.asp) to display a page saying, download chrome if it's detected they're using IE.

Comment: Must user we deal with is in the agricultural business and the reason they use outdated bowers is because they think that is the only browsers.